# android studios no refreshed token showing up on logcat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't seem to get the refreshed token on the logcat, i guess its the final thing i need to test if my notification works.

Both the gradle files are at the bottom

below are the codes:

**Main Activity Class**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    private static final int ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST = 9001;

    private Button btnAbout;
    private Button btnContact;
    private Button btnVideos;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAbout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAbout);
        btnAbout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openAbout();
            }
        });

        btnContact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnContact);
        btnContact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                openContact();
            }
        });

        btnVideos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVideos);
        btnVideos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                openVideos();
            }
        });

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel mChannel =
                    new NotificationChannel(Constants.CHANNEL_ID, Constants.CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

            mChannel.setDescription(Constants.CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);

            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400 ,500 ,400, 300, 200, 400});

            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }

        common.currentToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        Log.d("My Token", common.currentToken);

        if(isServicesOK())

            init();
    }

    private void init(){

        Button btnMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMap);
        btnMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isServicesOK(){
        Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: checking google services version");

        int available = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(MainActivity.this);

        if(available == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            //everything is okay
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: Google Play services is working");
            return true;
        }else if(GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(available)){
            // an error occured but we can resolve it
            Log.d(TAG, "isServicesOK: an error occured but we can fix it");
            Dialog dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(MainActivity.this, available, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST);
            dialog.show();

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "we cant make map requests", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void openAbout(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, About.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openContact(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Contact.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void openVideos(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Videos.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

**FirebaseMessagingService Class**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;


import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessagingService";

    public FirebaseMessagingService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        MyNotificationManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
                .displayNotification(title, body);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {

    }

}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.lrtapp.ardentmap">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/erlogo"
        android:label="EaseRoute"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyALC_Pis5w391INiqcvnXO7dipxuMP0-JA" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MapActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".About" />
        <activity android:name=".Contact" />
        <activity android:name=".Videos"></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
            android:exported="false"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>


        <service android:name=".FirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".MyFirebaseIdService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>



        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/colorAccent"/>



    </application>

</manifest>
```

**My Notification Manager Class**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MyNotificationManager {

    private Context mCtx;
    private static MyNotificationManager mInstance;

    private MyNotificationManager(Context context){
        mCtx = context;
    }

    public static synchronized MyNotificationManager getInstance(Context context){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new MyNotificationManager(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void displayNotification(String title, String body){

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mCtx, Constants.CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mCtx, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mCtx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);


        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mCtx.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if(mNotificationManager != null){
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }

    }
}
```

**Constants Class**

```
package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

public class Constants {

    public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "mychannelid";
    public static final String CHANNEL_NAME = "mychannelname";
    public static final String CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION = "myDescription";

}
Class for google map

package com.lrtapp.ardentmap;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.media.Image;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.gcm.Task;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "map is ready", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: map is ready");
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);

            init();
        }
    }

    private static final String TAG = "MapActivity";

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COURSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;
    private static final float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;

    //widgets
    private EditText mSearchText;
    private ImageView mGps;

    //vars

    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        mSearchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        mGps = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ic_gps);

        getLocationPermission();

    }

    private void init(){
        Log.d(TAG, "init: Initializing");

        mSearchText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH
                        || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE
                        ||  keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                        || keyEvent.getAction() == keyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){

                    //execute method for searching
                    geoLocate();

                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        mGps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked gps icon");
                getDeviceLocation();

            }
        });

        hideSoftKeyboard();
    }

    private void geoLocate(){
        Log.d(TAG, "geoLocate: geolocating");

        String searchString = mSearchText.getText().toString();

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(MapActivity.this);
        List<Address> list = new ArrayList<>();
        try{
            list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(searchString, 1);
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "geoLocate: IOException" + e.getMessage());
        }
        if(list.size() > 0){
            Address address = list.get(0);

            Log.d(TAG, "GeoLocate: found a Location: " +address.toString());

           // Toast.makeText(this, address.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT()).show();

            moveCamera(new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                    address.getAddressLine(0));
        }
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: getting the device's current location.");

        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted){

                final com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            Log.d(TAG, "Found Location");
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();

                                moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                        DEFAULT_ZOOM,
                                        "My Location");

                        }else{
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: current Location is null");
                            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, "unable to get current location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "getDeviceLocation: SecurityException: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        super.finalize();
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom, String title){
        Log.d(TAG, "moving the camera to: lat: " + latLng.latitude + ", lng: " +latLng.longitude);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,zoom));

        if(!title.equals("My Location")){
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(latLng)
                    .title(title);

            mMap.addMarker(options);
        }
        hideSoftKeyboard();

    }

    private void initMap(){
        Log.d(TAG, "initMap: initializing map");
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapActivity.this);
    }

    private void getLocationPermission(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
            initMap();

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: called.");
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode){
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length > 0){
                    for(int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++){
                        if(grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                            mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission failed.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: permission granted.");
                    //initializing map
                    initMap();

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void hideSoftKeyboard(){
        this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

}
```

**Project Gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven{
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Module/App Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.lrtapp.ardentmap"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    implementation 'me.biubiubiu.justifytext:library:1.1'

    //Google Play Services
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

any kind of help will be very appreciated. thanks in advance to those who will respond to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello @Zeke you will found the new refreshed token here in the following file then after you can store it and use it anywhere in the application

```
public class InstanceIDListenerService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
    public static String refreshedToken = "";
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
       refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
       Log.d("TOKEN=>", refreshedToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: should i place this on the mainactivity? thanks though, and where would i call this class?

Comment: thanks! this generated a token for me.

Comment: Welcome dear, if you want to get token in your MainActivity than for that you should create one local broadcast receiver so whenever new token is generated or refreshed then it will call the MainActivity and using that call you can perform your further stuff in MainActivity. if any doubt than please ask me don't hesitate.

Answer (score 0):

add log.d to logcat or u can show on textview or toast

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
public class GetTokenFireBase extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The registration token is generated the first time that the user starts the app, and may be [refreshed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register) after that.

Since generating the token requires calls to the Firebase servers and take some time, it happens asynchronously in the background. If your current log statement doesn't show a token, it is likely that the Firebase SDK is still waiting for the server to generate the token.

When a new token is generated, the Firebase SDK calls the `FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh()` method.

This means that you'll typically get the current token in two places:

1. In your app's main flow (e.g. `MainActivity.onCreate`) by calling `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()`
2. In your app's `FirebaseInstanceIdService.onTokenRefresh()` to capture when the token gets generated/refreshed.

For more on this, see the [documentation on getting the registration token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register).